# Error mounting /dev/sda2

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a problem with a hard disk. This used to be in my Lacie Network Space 2, but it crashed.

Under Windows I don't get to see anything, of course, so I ordered a USB - SATA cable, and a live boot USB from Ubuntu.

So far, that's what I have done. Because otherwise I am a layman and I try everything to get my photos/videos back.

To be precise, when I start Ubuntu, I get the following message when I click on the disk:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu /cea89a46-6cf3-492e-80f3-d270280237ac: can't read superblock on /dev/sda2
```

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Simple. This assumes that sda2 is an ext2/3/4 file system. If it's not, we have to do something else.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`